# How to fix "Unexpected end of JSON"

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ember.js, ember-data

I had my users page displaying users but then when I stopped working on the code for a while and came back to it I am getting an error which says

> Error while processing route: users Unexpected end of JSON input SyntaxError: Unexpected end of JSON input

and also

> Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected end of JSON input

I don't know where to start on trying to fix this issue.

Here is the front-end code in the route file users.js:

```
model() {
  return this.get("store").findAll("user");
},
```

Here is the api code in the users controller:

```
# GET /users
  def index
    render jsonapi: User.all
  end
```

When I go to http://localhost:3000/users I get the following json:

```
{
    data: [
        {
        id: "1",
            type: "users",
            attributes: {
                name: "Katie",
                email: "katie@gmail.com"
            }
        },
        {
            id: "2",
            type: "users",
            attributes: {
                name: "Katie",
                email: "katie@gmail.com"
            }
        },
        {
            id: "3",
            type: "users",
            attributes: {
                name: "Katie",
                email: "katie@gmail.com"
            }
        },
        {
            id: "4",
            type: "users",
            attributes: {
                name: "K",
                email: "k"
            }
        },
        {
            id: "5",
            type: "users",
            attributes: {
                name: "R",
                email: "r"
            }
      }
    ],
    jsonapi: {
        version: "1.0"
    }
}
```

I also get this warning: WARNING: The server returned an empty string for GET http://localhost:3000/users, which cannot be parsed into a valid JSON. Return either null or {}.

Comment: I'm not familiar enough with rails to know if that controller will work, could you post the JSON that visiting `/users` outputs? I've gotten this error before when my backend was munging output in some way (adding debugging HTML, sending the wrong headers, etc).

Comment: I've never seen `render jsonapi`, maybe you meant `render json: User.all`?

Comment: Hi @jrjohnson , I added the json. I'm using the json api gem.

Answer (score 0):

`/users` route is not providing the valid JSON output is the reason for this error. You can check `/users` output using POSTMAN or writing the below code,

```
let url ="/users";
Ember.$.getJSON(url).then((result) => {
 console.log(' Result ', result);
});
```

Comment: Thanks, I have added the json that I am getting to the question.

Comment: @Chris It looks valid json. I think type should be  `type: "user"` instead of ` type: "users"`